# How to add authority control when join channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have read the fabric source code about `peer join channel` , this step will invoke to create chain ledger (database) .
Now I wanna to manage this step, someone want to join the channel must be accepted , but how to get the accept message according to the chain ? As the current peer has not create ledger, so it is impossible to get the accept message.Do you have some ideas to add authority control when join channel ?
My ideas :

> 1. create a common chain which everybody must join when start, we can get the accept from the common chain
>
> 2.orderer create grpc interface and save a white list (who could join the channel now), peer must know he is in the while list from orderer
>   ,then he could join channel successfully.But orderer must be consistency with other orderer.

Answer (score 1):

Any peer that its organization is in the channel can join the channel. If you want to specify only a subset of peers from joining the channel, I suggest you simply have a more delicate separation of the organization.

I suggest you read the [MSP section](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html) for more background and intuition about how the process works.

Comment: We do not use its organization information when join channel.  Someone could join channel if the peers who have joined in channel  all agree , but the one is a different organization.

Comment: Thats a great idea, like an endorsement policy in place at channel level which can specify who all should approve when someone joins the channel.